# STR9 getting minutes to a variable

Tags: microcontroller

```
/* Wait for the alarm flag */
while (!RTC_GetFlagStatus(RTC_FLAG_Alarm)); /* do polling or RTC alarm flag*/
RTC_GetTime(BINARY,&time);                 /*time structure must be equal to alarm time*/

lcd_clear();
lcd_print ("Alarm occured at");
set_cursor (0, 1);
sprintf(text, "time: %2dh%2dm%2ds ",time.hours,time.minutes,time.seconds);
lcd_print (text);
```

Hello all,
The above code section is from RTC example (STR9). This part gives a display of the time ( Hrs, minutes, seconds)

How is it possible to assign the minutes ( time.minutes) to a variable ( say 'y')

When i give

```
y = time.minutes;
sprintf(text, "Minutes :%04d",y);
lcd_print (text);
```

I dont get any values at y. It is always 0.

Do anyone know how to get that?

Comment: We're just supposed to know what "STR9" is!?

Comment: @matt, we have many very experienced members but many of them have not used physically every product because it is impossible to do so. If you give us links to where you are getting information and what you are using you will find many of the experts here will answer your question without the product just applying their own experience to the manual you have.

Comment: I don't think he meant bad. Maybe it's his first time in such a site, even maybe first time asking a question? When you Google STR9, it pops-up in the first line.

Comment: In the microcontroller business, yes, knowing an str from a pic (pic12, pic18, dspic, pic32) from an msp from an avr, etc are all expected to be known.  it is an arm based microcontroller from st.  arm9 based like the str7 is arm7 based, etc.  I agree more detail should have been included, perhaps the specific part not the family, even better a link.

Comment: http://www.st.com/internet/mcu/subclass/828.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Does the example code you pasted at the top work - the LCD shows [h]h[m]m[s]s? If so, there is no clear reason to believe, based on the limited information you've provided, that the second code snippet shouldn't work as well...

Maybe try using the same exact format string?

```
y = time.minutes;
sprintf(text, "Minutes: %2d",y);
lcd_print (text);
```

Perhaps your compiler doesn't support the leading zeros formatting option (i.e. %0)?

If, however, your original snippet doesn't work either, it seems very likely that you are fundamentally failing to communicate with the RTC in the first place.

Comment: The original snippet worked successfully. I tried using the exact format string. But am not getting the correct value. It is just a zero coming up

Comment: we'll need more context... the full code posted to www.pastebin.com would be helpful, which microcontroller are you using, which compiler/ide...

Comment: ok.. I got it... The problem was the initialization. I initialzed int as int ( variable y) and now it works.

Comment: @matt cool! thanks for updating... still would be good to add what compiler/ide and microcontroller you were using here...